# Email validation not working in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

this is my input

```
aby-saturn@gmail.com
```

hyphen is not working in emailid getting invalid email id
this is my ng-pattern

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/" noncapitalize required />
    </div>
    <div style="color: red" id="emailError"></div>
    <span style="color:red;" class="email-error" ng-show="loginForm.submitted && loginForm.email.$error.required">Required</span>
    <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-show="loginForm.submitted && loginForm.email.$error.pattern">Email not valid</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can remove the `ng-pattern` if you don't really need it. HTMLs `type="email"` should be sufficient, shouldn't it ?

Comment: you need a regExp to validate an email, or you need the particular `regExp` in your question. bcoz you seems to have an issue with your `regex`

Comment: @Sravan i need a regExp to validate an email not a particular one thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `regexp` for email validation.

**`^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$`**

You can test this regexp [here](https://regex101.com/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
<body ng-app="">

<p>Try writing in the input field:</p>

<form name="myForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-pattern="/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$/" noncapitalize required />
    </div>
    <div style="color: red" id="emailError"></div>
    <span style="color:red;" class="email-error" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Required</span>
    <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.pattern">Email not valid</span>
</div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[Here is a working **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4q2BsETFr48IKSaHxzM?p=preview)

Comment: Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't want to allow '-' to be in the email address, here is what I got using `ng-pattern` and if you want '-' to be allowed check 2nd example:

1) If '-' is not allowed:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
      email: 'test@test.com'
    };

    $scope.emailPattern = /^(([^-<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <form name="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-pattern="emailPattern" noncapitalize required />
      </div>
      <div style="color: red" id="emailError">
        <span style="color:red;" class="email-error" ng-show="loginForm.email.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-show="loginForm.email.$error.pattern">Email not valid, doesn't match the provided pattern</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

2) If '-' is allowed:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
      email: 'test@test.com'
    };

    $scope.emailPattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <form name="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-pattern="emailPattern" noncapitalize required />
      </div>
      <div style="color: red" id="emailError">
        <span style="color:red;" class="email-error" ng-show="loginForm.email.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-show="loginForm.email.$error.pattern">Email not valid, doesn't match the provided pattern</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```